# Computing log-determinant?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

Mathematica does-not have a function to compute the log-det of matrix? Naively computing `Log[Det[M]]` can be numerically unstable.

Comment: If speed isn't an issue, you could just do a `SingularValueDecomposition`, take the log of the singular values and take the `Total`

Comment: Yes, speed (and memory) are an issue. Having to compute and store all the singular vectors is very wasteful.

Comment: `SingularValueList` is about 2-3 times faster, and I would like to know too if there are significantly better ways to compute the log-determinant.

Comment: `LUDecomposition` is much faster, but potentially less stable. So, something like `Total[Log[Abs[Diagonal[First[LUDecomposition[m]]]]]]` should work (this removes the sign of the determinant, though)

Comment: Yes, I am assuming the determinant is positive. In fact assume `M` is posdef, so instead of LU we can use Cholesky. But still this seems more expensive than required?

Comment: For general $\mathbf M$, I don't expect that you can do better than $O(n^3)$ effort for $\log\det\mathbf M$, even if it's SPD. But if the matrix has some sort of exploitable structure, perhaps...

Comment: Hope the Wolfram team can add such a function soon!